# Excel, Using Rand between Function Once Inside IF function with roughly 10 outcomes based on the value returned. (only 1 Cel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use an if function to generate random data for practicing purposes for my Colleague.

The formula goes as follows:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(E70)=1,"",(IF(E70="Shell Head office and Back",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)<3,"MeetingatHeadOffice",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)<6,"Report Submission","Training")),IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)<7,"Inspect - Oil Damage Claim",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)<5,"Claim Finding Discussion","Incident Isolation")))))
```

This is a rough Idea of how I want to generate practice information for my Colleague to recon. There are multiple functions just like this one within the Document. I want to Lessen the Rand between function to only 1 and have multiple conditions with multiple outcomes as above.

Comment: FYI, your formula as built will compute RANDBETWEEN 4 times, possibly giving you 4 different answers which will probably lead to following a different `if()` path than intended.

Answer (score 0):

Say we wanted to implement:

[image]

But we want the formula to not repeat `RANDBETWEEN()` over and over and over.  We can use `CHOOSE()` as follows:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),"A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D")
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a solution that contains only one `RANDBETWEEN()`, but needs a small distribution table to drive it.  Place the 10 options in column **A**.  Place the required percentages (**as integer**) in column **B**  In **C1** enter:

```
=B1
```

in **C2** enter:

```
=B2+C1
```

and copy downward.  Column **C** represents the cumulative distribution (**as integer**):

[image]

In the above table we want
10% A
5% B
6% C
etc.

Finally in **F1** enter:

=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($C$1:$C$10>=RANDBETWEEN(1,100),0),))

I could not avoid the extra table.

[image]

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to Use a certain percentage chance with the formula instead?, For example if I were to have my randbetween  go from 1 to 100?. That will end up being too much to type in the end and I wont be allowed to type it all because of the letter limit in Excel.

Comment: @Daniel yes...........check back later today......................

Comment: @Garry's Student Please let me know if you get back. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel  See my **EDIT#1**